# Prompt toolkit write multiline input to file and close the prompt

Tags: python, prompt

I would like to make some form of terminal editor for text-based files.

When started, it prints the current content of the file and makes it possible for user to edit in (multiline input). On press of CTRL + E, it should write that multiline input into specific file and close the prompt.

I have tried using this code, but it doesn't seem to work.

```py
from prompt_toolkit import prompt, PromptSession
from prompt_toolkit.lexers import PygmentsLexer
from pygments.lexers.python import PythonLexer
from prompt_toolkit.formatted_text import HTML
from prompt_toolkit.key_binding import KeyBindings

file_path = 'output.txt'
file = open(file_path, 'r')  
content = file.read()
new_content = None

session = PromptSession()
bindings = KeyBindings()    

@bindings.add('c-e')
def _(event):
    global new_content
    global file_path

    file = open(file_path, 'w') 
    file.write(new_content)     

    session.app.exit()


def show_prompt():
    global new_content
    global session

    bottom_toolbar = HTML('<b><style background-color="white" color="green">Input</style></b>') 
    lexer = PygmentsLexer(PythonLexer)
    new_content = session.prompt('\n', 
                        default=content, 
                        lexer=lexer,
                        multiline=True,
                        bottom_toolbar=bottom_toolbar,
                        key_bindings=bindings)

# Start of the program
if __name__ == '__main__':
    show_prompt()
```

Comment: whats not working

Comment: I can't get the current multiline input. It simply returns None. I want to be able to press CTRL + E and get current multiline input.